# How to use 2 asp.net projects together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm working on a web application with asp.net mvc 4 and I want to do a administration interface,but I want do it in other visual studio's project. So I don't how it works, the routing, how connect to the database from other project. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Jorge is right, you don't need to create project just for separating the admin Panel, in asp.net MVC you can create areas for admin part

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps.

1. Create one solution
2. Add two projects to the same solution
3. Point the web.config of the two projects to the same database

It doesn't have to be so complicated with routing, because each project belong to a different site and a different environment.

In my opinion you should create just want project and define a new area for the administration